# how to use Auth0 access token from frontend-react used in my backend

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, auth0

i'm trying to do a react app with a kotlin backend using auth0 as auth server.
I've the auth0-spa integrated in my react app so i can do a login, but the token i'm receiving ios an opaque token so when i'm sending to my app to authenticate my users, it's not a valid jwt (It's just a alphanumeric code without 3 jwt parts).

I'm reading that it's because auth0 spa framework does not allow to change response type to sokmething else than code so access token received it only works for /userinfo api os auth0.

My doubt is, how do i can use that token in my backend to validate it still using auth0-spa? Is there anyway or should i use auth0 non spa library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the backend as an audience in the request for the token. The opaque token is only valid for auth0 apis.